# How do I enable a mac-style global application menu in classic desktop edition?

Tags: 10.10, panel, ayatana, appmenu

How do I enable a mac-style global application menu in classic desktop edition of Ubuntu 10.10?

Answer (score 2):

Install the package `indicator-applet-appmenu`. Then right click on the panel, select 'Add to Panel...', select 'Indicator Applet Appmenu' and click 'Add'.

[image: Add to Panel]

Comment: Doesn't work. Shows only "File" and "Edit" menus and even those don't open on click.

Comment: Wrong URL, The appmenu is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-appmenu

Answer (score 2):

There is already an app menu avaible; though another one has been developed for use in Ubuntu Unity.

Please be warned that as of this time, some applications (like Firefox) do not work with the appmenu.